# How to Escape Special Characters in Apache solr in php

Tags: php, solr4

I want to escape the special character from this solr query

stringfield:/"name":"Elan"/.

I try this one
 stringfield:/\".*name.*\":\".*Elan.*\"/ 
but its not working.Is there any other ways to solve this ?

Comment: I guess we need a bit more info to be able to help you. How do you perform the query? Are you using a PHP client lib? If yes, which one? Can you provide a code snippet about how you generate the query?

Comment: This is my php code      $solrq .= '&fq=stringfield:/\'.urlencode($_POST['name'])/'/;   .Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not getting your setup, but I guess you do a bit too much escaping. And the query in your question looks kind of odd concerning the addressing of fields.

A filter query should only consist of `field:value`, not `field1:field2:value` or something...

As a tip, try to assemble the URL manually and get it working. Or use the Solr Admin UI, where you can assemble your query in a form-based manner. You'll also get the query URL from there.

Have you tried to print the URL you assemble in your PHP code and invoke it manually?

Your query URL should look simply like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=*&fq=myfield:"myvalue"
```

or URL-escaped:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=*&fq=myfield%3A%22myvalue%22
```

I guess, your PHP code should look like this:

```
$solrq .= '&fq=stringfield:"' . urlencode($_POST['name']) . '"';
```

where `$_POST['name']` is hopefully just `Elan`.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.But i have column as "name" in indexed file,If i send Elan only it takes all values where the elan is available.Actually i want a Particular column which has the values as Elan,Is there any possibilities in solr querying.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. Do you mean, your field is not called 'stringfield' but 'name'? Have you tried this then: $solrq .= '&fq=name:"' . urlencode($_POST['name']) . '"';